# When does a place become a shul w/r/t saying me'ein sheva Friday nights?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, synagogue, leil-shabbat, location

[Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 268:10](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1467) plus commentaries gives the rule that *me'ein sheva* (*magen avot* etc) isn't said at a private home, because it lacks the regularity of a shul.

If someone has a regular minyan at their home, at what point can it be considered a shul? The Mishnah Berurah there mentions having a sefer Torah - is this a hard-and-fast requirement, or is consistency over a certain (what?) period of time all that's needed?

Answer (score 1):

Shulchan Aruch Harav ([268:15](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3447052/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-268-Laws-Governing-One-Who-Errs-in-Shabbos-Prayers.htm)) writes:

> אין אומרים ברכה מעין ז' אלא בבית הכנסת קבוע דהיינו בכל מקום שמתפללין בו בעשרה בקביעות אבל מקום שמתפללין בו בעשרה באקראי בעלמא כגון אותן שעושים לפרקים מנין בביתם וכן בבית חתנים ואבלים שעושים מנין בביתם אין לומר שם ברכת מעין ז' ... ואם קובעים מקום להתפלל בו בעשרה איזה זמן כגון בירידין שרגילים לקבוע מקום על כמה שבועות יש מי שהורה לאמרה שם שגם שם יש המאחרין לבוא ובמקום שנהגו לאמרה אף במנין שהוא באקראי בעלמא אין למחות בידם (כיון שלא נזכר דבר זה בגמרא ובדברי הגאונים)
>
> The one blessing that encapsulates seven should be recited only in an
> established synagogue, i.e., a place where ten people pray together in an
> ongoing manner. This blessing should not, by contrast, be recited in a place
> where ten people pray on occasion, for example, people who from time to time
> make a minyan in their homes, or in the home of a groom,
> or mourners who make a minyan in their homes ... If a place is established as a place of prayer for ten people for a specific period – e.g., at trading fairs, it is commonplace to establish places of prayer for several weeks – there is an authority who ruled that [this blessing] should be recited there, because in such a situation, there are also people who come late [to the services]. In a locale where it is customary to recite [this blessing] even in a place where people pray only on occasion, they should not be reproved for doing so, (since this matter is not mentioned in the Talmud or the words of the Geonim).

It would appear from this that as soon as it is decided to *daven* there on a set basis, they may say *me'ein sheva*.